# all integers which are subsequences of an integer (considered as a string of digits)

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer 1<=n<=100000. How do I get efficiently all the integers which are subsequences of the integer n (considering the integer n as a string of digits). I want a pseudo code for this.

eg. **input:** `n=121`, **output:** `1,12,11,2,21` (the order of output has no importance)

eg. **input:** `n=132`, **output:** `1,13,12,3,32,2`

thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: You can consider "digit x is in the number" as a binary number... BTW, your example is ambiguous. Given `123`, would `31` be a subsequence?

Comment: the digits of the number n are in [0-9], and 31 is not a valid subsequence of 123. an other example: n=132, output:1,13,12,3,32,2.

Comment: Why? Looks like one of those homework assignments.

Comment: it's not a homework assignment. it's a question I think of and don't found a solution.

Comment: The problem cleanly breaks down into three parts. Convert an integer to a string of digits, generate the string subsequences, convert each subsequence back into an integer. So why don't you ask just about the interesting part?

Comment: I want the question to be general to allow direct solutions without the string conversion steps if possible.

Comment: General? In what way is it general? The question about subsequences of an arbitrary sequence is general.

Comment: I mean I don't want to restrict solutions provided there is integer as input and output.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what is meant by "general" and "restricted". You are getting them exactly backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another version, using recursion. This one uses just integer division and modulo (both combined in [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)) to get the 'sub-integers'. It's done in Python, which is just as good as pseudo code...

```py
def subints(n):
    d, r = divmod(n, 10)
    if d > 0:
        for s in subints(d):
            yield 10*s + r
            yield    s
    yield r
```

Example: (a `set` of the resulting numbers would be enough; using `list` for better understanding)

```py
>>> print list(subints(1234))
[1234, 123, 124, 12, 134, 13, 14, 1, 234, 23, 24, 2, 34, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Very efficient solution in python. Can you code the recursive algorithm in C++ even in a less efficient way, it would be of good use for C++ users.

Comment: @bilbo Certainly you can do the same in C/C++, but I know  C too little for that. You basically just have to replace all those `yield` statements with adding to some list or set and then return that list/set.

Answer (score 2):

n=121

length = 3

Generate all possible binary numbers of length 3. See the `set bits` in binary number and print the corresponding digit from the original number.

Example 1

```
121   length=3

000  -> 0    (ignore this:no bit set)
001  -> 1    (__1)
010  -> 2    (_2_)
011  -> 21   (_21)
100  -> 1    (repeated: ignore this)
101  -> 11   (1_1)
110  -> 12   (12_)
111  -> 121  (121)
```

Example 2: n=1234

```
1234  length=4

0000  -> 0    (ignore this:no bit set)
0001  -> 4    (___4)
0010  -> 3    (__3_)
0011  -> 34   (__34)
0100  -> 2    (_2__)
0101  -> 24   (_2_4)
0110  -> 23   (_23_)
0111  -> 234  (_234)
1000  -> 1    (1___)
1001  -> 14   (1__4)
1010  -> 13   (1_3_)
1011  -> 134  (1_34)
1100  -> 12   (12__)
1101  -> 124  (12_4)
1110  -> 123  (123_)
1111  -> 1234 (1234)
```

The code for the above algorithm made by me in `C` is pasted below. I have not performed many optimizations but the logic is same.

*Sorry for the unoptimized code.*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 30
main()
{
    int i,j,end,index,k,swap;
    char str[SIZE],arr[SIZE];
    char buffer[SIZE],dict[SIZE][SIZE]={'\0'};  //dictlength is used to store the 
    int dictlength=0;
    gets(str);
    for(i=1;i<pow(2,strlen(str));i++)
    {
        index=0;
        end=strlen(str);
        itoa(i,arr,2);
        for(j=strlen(arr);j>=0;j--,end--)
        {
            if(arr[j]=='1')
            {
                buffer[index]=str[end];
                index=index+1;
            }
        }
        buffer[index]='\0';
        for(k=0,j=strlen(buffer)-1; k<j ; k++,j--)
        {
            swap=buffer[k];
            buffer[k]=buffer[j];
            buffer[j]=swap;
        }
        strcpy(dict[dictlength],buffer);
        dictlength++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<dictlength;i++)
        puts(dict[i]);
}
```

Comment: for 121 , the output set contains 11

Comment: it's a good idea, can you add a pseudo-code algorithm for this.

Comment: Yeah sure, wait for a while.

Comment: @Jerky Why not include that code into your question? Would be a shame should that link be no longer available in the future.

Comment: @tobias_k it's included now :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    static HashSet<string> Subseq(string input, HashSet<string> result = null, int pos = 0, string current = "")
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        if (pos == input.Length)
        {
            return result;
        }

        Subseq(input, result, pos + 1, current);

        current += input[pos];
        if (!result.Contains(current))
        {
            result.Add(current);
        }

        Subseq(input, result, pos + 1, current);

        return result;
    }
```

Called as:

```
var result = Subseq("18923928");
```

If you don't consider "123" a subsequence of "123", then just add the condition `current != input` to the last `if`.